# Add child note above node

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Am trying to get from SQL to XML however have to format this correctly or it will not work. I am using C# to insert my sql between the QBXML

```
select employee_name as Name ,'OCI Associates' as [CompanyName],'Mr' as Salutation ,
 LEFT(employee_name,CHARINDEX(' ',employee_name + ' ')-1) as FirstName,  REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(employee_name),
CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(employee_name))- 1)) AS LastName


  from EMPLOYEELIST 
for xml raw('CustomerAdd') , ROOT('CustomerAddRq'), ELEMENTS
```

This is what I get

```
<CustomerAdd>
        <Name>Zohreh FAKELASTNAME</Name>
        <Salutation>Mr</Salutation>
        <FirstName>Zohreh</FirstName>
        <LastName>FAKELASTNAME</LastName>
      </CustomerAdd>
      <CustomerAdd>
        <Name>Phillip FAKELASTNAME</Name>
        <Salutation>Mr</Salutation>
        <FirstName>Phillip</FirstName>
        <LastName>FAKELASTNAME</LastName>
      </CustomerAdd>
```

This is what I need

'''

```
 <CustomerAddRq>
<CustomerAdd>
        <Name>Zohreh FAKELASTNAME</Name>
        <Salutation>Mr</Salutation>
        <FirstName>Zohreh</FirstName>
        <LastName>FAKELASTNAME</LastName>
      </CustomerAdd>
 </CustomerAddRq>
 <CustomerAddRq>
  <CustomerAdd>
    <Name>Phillip FAKELASTNAME</Name>
    <Salutation>Mr</Salutation>
    <FirstName>Phillip</FirstName>
    <LastName>FAKELASTNAME</LastName>
  </CustomerAdd>
```

'''

I am not sure how to add the "CustomerAddRq" over each "CustomerAdd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq.  I took a string array of you elements which I assume was coming from the database and then added to you root node.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] xmlArray = {
                                    "<CustomerAdd>" +
                                      "<Name>Zohreh FAKELASTNAME</Name>" +
                                      "<Salutation>Mr</Salutation>" +
                                      "<FirstName>Zohreh</FirstName>" +
                                      "<LastName>FAKELASTNAME</LastName>" +
                                    "</CustomerAdd>",
                                    "<CustomerAdd>" +
                                      "<Name>Phillip FAKELASTNAME</Name>" +
                                      "<Salutation>Mr</Salutation>" +
                                      "<FirstName>Phillip</FirstName>" +
                                      "<LastName>FAKELASTNAME</LastName>" +
                                    "</CustomerAdd>"
                                };
            XElement customerAddRq = new XElement("CustomerAddRq");
            customerAddRq.Add(xmlArray.Select(x => XElement.Parse(x)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please - for your next question - always tag with your actual RDBMS (vendor and version). You've tagged with `[sql]` which is not enough...

From your code I assume this is SQL Server.

You can try this:

Create a *mockup table* to simulate your issue (please do this yourself the next time)

```
DECLARE @fakeTable TABLE(employee_name VARCHAR(100), salutation VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @fakeTable VALUES
 ('Zohreh FAKELASTNAME','Mr')
,('One MORE','Ms')
```

--Your own query, slightly changed

```
select employee_name as [CustomerAdd/Name] 
      ,'OCI Associates' as [CustomerAdd/CompanyName]
      , salutation as [CustomerAdd/Salutation]
      , LEFT(employee_name,CHARINDEX(' ',employee_name + ' ')-1) as [CustomerAdd/FirstName]
      ,  REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(employee_name),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(employee_name))- 1)) AS [CustomerAdd/LastName]
from @fakeTable EMPLOYEELIST 
for xml PATH('CustomerAddRq');
```

The idea in short:

I use `PATH`-mode. This allows for a XPath expression in the column's alias.
The `ROOT` will be the outermost element, appearing just once. The name after `PATH('ThisName')` will appear around any row.
Now comes the magic:

- The engine opens the row's tag and finds an element as `[CustomerAdd/Name]`.
- It will write the opening tag `<CustomerAdd>` and then the opening tag `<Name>`.
- Into this element it will write the content as `text()` node.
- Now the engine finds `<CustomerAdd/CompanyName>`.
- The engine will close `<Name>`, but - as still within `<CustomerAdd>` - will continue here and opens `<CompanyName>`
- ...and so on...